# Text Input Rotation + Styling the text

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, textinput

I have `textInput` on stage, it's not the component; but rather a `textField` which is set to behave as `inputText`. I also have a button on stage to bold the selected portion of the text in the `inputField`.

Here's the code, which works perfectly fine:

```
var formatDefBold: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
formatDefBold.bold = false;
var formatBold: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
formatBold.bold = true;

boldBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeBold);

function makeBold(event: MouseEvent):void
{
    var sbi:Number = myInputField.selectionBeginIndex;
    var sei:Number = myInputField.selectionEndIndex;

    if (sbi != sei)
    {
        var section:TextFormat = myInputField.getTextFormat(sbi,sei);

        if (section.bold == false)
        {
            myInputField.setTextFormat(formatBold, sbi, sei);
        }
        else
        {
            myInputField.setTextFormat(formatDefBold, sbi, sei);
        }
        stage.focus = this[selectedTextField]; // highlight the selected text again.
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
When I rotate the textInput, the text disappears. If I embed the font and choose another anti-aliasing method like "Anti-Alias for animation", the rotated textInput displays the text fine, but the `makeBold` function doesn't work.
I've tried different fonts. Sans, Arial, which I embedded all it's styles (Bold, Italic, Bold-Italic). nothing!

I've tried placing the `textInput` inside a `movieClip` and rotate the `movieClip` instead. doesn't work.

I've also tried setting the `embedFonts` parameter for the `textInput` too, not sure if I did it correctly

```
myInputField.embedFonts = true;
```

this time the text disappears even when the `textField` is not rotated.

I'm really stuck and can't think of anything else to make the bold function work with a rotated `textInput`.

Answer (score 1):

**Embedding method**

For any operations like rotation applied to a text field, you should first embed the text font.

```
myText.text = "rotation with embed font";
myText.rotation = 10;
```

Your text field 'myText' is physically put on the scene. When you click on it, in the window 'Properties', do that:

- anti-alias (Anti-alias for animation)
- font embed

To embed the font, click on 'embed' button > window 'Font Embedding' > 'Character ranges' > select: 'Uppercase', 'Lowercase', 'Numerals', 'Punctuation'. (don't click on 'All')

**3D method**

You can also rotate a dynamic text field without embedding fonts using the 3D methods available in Flash Player 10.

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
this.addChild(myTextField);

var fo:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 11, 0xFF0000);

myTextField.defaultTextFormat = fo;
myTextField.text = "3D rotation";
myTextField.rotationZ = 45;
```

**In your case...**

In your case, the following code works perfectly (you just have to put a button named 'boldBtn' on your scene):

```
var myInputField:TextField = new TextField();
this.addChild(myInputField);

var fo:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana", 12, 0x000000, false);

myInputField.defaultTextFormat = fo;
myInputField.text = "3D rotation";
myInputField.rotationZ = 45;

boldBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeBold);

function makeBold(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fo.bold = !fo.bold;
    myInputField.setTextFormat(fo);
}
```

Comment: the 2nd method which is through actionscript works. but the 1st one which has the myTextFiled on stage, doesn't work. I tried embedding the font the way you said (not selecting all...) whenever I enable anti-aliasing for animation the bold function stops working; even if I don't rotate the textField

Comment: I set the anti-aliasing to it's default value which is "use device fonts" and used rotationZ to rotate the text field. and it worked!
using rotation (not rotationZ) with default anti-aliasing doesn't show the text. 
and using rotation (not rotationZ) with anti-aliasing makes the bold function not work.

Comment: @Milad Ghattavi - I'm glad to have helped you. You don't need to create two text formats. As shown in my example, you just have to change 'bold' property of your textFormat, and to set it to your textField with setTextFormat() method.

Answer (score 0):

I set the anti-aliasing to it's default value which is "use device fonts" and used `rotationZ` to rotate the text field. and it worked!

using `rotation` (not `rotationZ`) with default anti-aliasing doesn't show the text.

and using `rotation` (not `rotationZ`) with anti-aliasing makes the bold function not work.

so this is solved with just adding this line of code:

```
myInputField.rotationZ = 45;
```